# How long does a Box-API refresh token last?

Tags: oauth-2.0, box-api

i'm writing an application which uploads files to the Box-API, for some clients but i'm having a problem i don't understand (I've laready opened a ticket for that but maybe you'll have some answers): The refresh token is expiring in almost one hour and sometimes less time.

I've no idea why this is happening and i though the refresh token was lasting one month, but i've installe the application on my client machine, the client authorized it in his box account, but after only half an hour he was propt to authorize it again cause the refresh token was "invalid".

What should i think?

I'm updating the refresh token everytime i get a new access token, so there shouldn't be problem with that. SHould i do otherwise? ANy idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two tokens:

- the `authentication` token, which signs the HTTP request, is valid for **1 hour**.
- the `refresh` token, which is used to get a new `authentication` token, is valid for **60 days** or until it is used.

Comment: If used after 60 days, does it renew?

Comment: The refresh token can no longer be used if it's 60+ days old. At that point, the user will need to reauthorize your application.